# $N_k$ is the number of pairs $(a,b)$ of non-negative integers such that $ka+(k+1)b=n+1-k$. Find $N_1+N_2+\cdots N_{n+1}$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, integers

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Assume that:

$N_k$ is the number of pairs $(a,b)$  of non-negative integers such that $ka+(k+1)b=n+1-k$.
Find $N_1+N_2+\cdots N_{n+1}$.

I was trying to solve this calculating coefficients of polynomial equations but in vain like:

We know that $N_k$ is the coefficient of $X^{n-k+1}$ in:

$$G_k(X)=(1+X^k+X^{2k}+\cdots)(1+X^{k+1}+X^{2k+2}+\cdots)$$

Now can you help me from here or by any other elegant way. Please help.

Comment: Is the answer $n$?

Comment: Here's a hint: by rearranging, we are trying count the number of solutions $(k,a,b)$ to $k(a+b+1)+b=n+1$ where $k,a,b$ are integers, $k\geq 1$ and $a,b\geq 0$. By making the change of variables $q=a+b+1$ and $r=b$, we are now trying to count the number of integer solutions $(k,q,r)$ to $kq+r=n+1$ where $k\geq 1$ and $0\leq r\leq q-1$. Look familiar?

Comment: @sku the amswer is $n+1$. You are close enough. Please give me the answer in detail.

Comment: @Munchhausen Please give me the answer in detail, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I took some examples. I got N(5) = 6; N(7) = 8. And so saw a pattern. Couple of things we can conclude. For $n$ even, $N_1 = n/2 + 1$, for $n$ odd, $N_1 = \frac{n+1}{2}$; Also $N_{n+1} = 1$ always. Also, for $ \frac{n+1}{2} < k < n+1, N_k = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Set $N=N_1+\dots+N_{n+1}$ and notice that $N$ is precisely the number of integer solutions $(k,a,b)$ to $ka+(k+1)b=n+1-k$ where $k\geq 1$ and $a,b\geq 0$. Setting $q=a+b+1$ and $r=b$ and rearranging the expression, $N$ is the number of integer solutions $(k,q,r)$ to $n+1=qk+r$ where $k\geq 1$ and $0\leq r\leq q-1$. But this expression is exactly what you get when dividing $n+1$ by $q$. More specifically, $k$ is the quotient, and $r$ is the remainder. Thus, we know that for every fixed $1\leq q\leq n+1$, there is precisely one integer solutions $(k,q,r)$ to $n+1=qk+r$ where $k\geq 1$ and $0\leq r\leq q-1$, so $N=n+1$.